# Footnote doesn't appear when put into a "definition" environment

Tags: footnotes, theorems

When I try to put a footnote into a `definition` environment (or `theorem`, etc.) it fails, whereas it works well in plain text...

How can I fix it? (N.B. I use `thmbox`, I don't know if this have an incidence).

Comment: Please provide a short, complete, example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail? provide a minimum working example? How does it not work? Does it fail to compile? Does it compile, but look wrong in some way? We can't help you unless you explain in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: OK. I made an MWE myself. The problem seems to be that it compiles, you get the footnote number, but the footnote itself is missing. Is this the same problem you are having, @nandayo?

Comment: I'm ,sorry, I just discover the way this site works, I thought I would receive a mail when answered (now I checked the options ;-) )

Yes, this is precisely this problem : the footnote number appears, but the footnote itself is absent.

Comment: Please see at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41100/missing-footnote-and-marginpar-with-package-thmbox-or-package-thmtools-with-opti and the answers which have been given there. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

Use `\footnotemark` inside the definition environment, then *outside* the environment (it might have to be after another paragraph) place `\footnotetext{...}`.

Worst case, you might have to hard-code the footnote number like `\footnotetext[7]{...}`.

Answer (score 5):

You may try  with the `ntheorem` package the pair `footnotemark/footnotetext`. Or use `mdframed`, which cooperates with `amsthm` as well as `ntheorem` ; it places the footnote at the end of the environment, somehow like threeparttable. Both work fine on the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed]{ntheorem}
\newframedtheorem{Prop}{Proposition}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor = lightgray]{proposition}[Prop]{Proposition}
\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}

\begin{document}

\begin{Prop}Example withc framed. \footnotemark\end{Prop}\footnotetext{Just to see! }

\begin{proposition}
Example with mdframed \footnote{Just to see! }
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Here is the resulting pdf:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same effect as for floats. Perhaps the combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` can help.

Comment: According to my MWE (which, I stress, might be different from the OPs problem) `\footnotemark[7]\footnotetext{foo}` doesn't work. It produces the right footnotemark, but the text is still missing.

Comment: Putting `\footnotetext{foo}` _outside_ the `thmbox` environment _almost_ works: the footnote text appears, but with the wrong mark: with a 0 in my case...

Comment: Same here, none of footnotemark or footnotetext works. You think the problem is linked to the use of the package thmbox ?