# Missing footnote and marginpar with package thmbox or package thmtools with option thmbox

Tags: footnotes, theorems, marginpar

I am using package `thmbox` to write theorems.  If I include `footnote` or `marginpar` within the body of a theorem, the following problems arise:  the text of the `footnote` is simply missing, while the `marginpar` produces the error `Float(s) lost.`, and then the text of the `marginpar` is also missing.  The same occurs with package `thmtools` with optin `thmbox`.  It seems that the first problem can be solved following the answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4486).  Is there a better solution?  What about the second problem?  An example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

% LaTeX original ==> OK
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% package thmbox ==> wrong
\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% package thmtools with option thmbox ==> wrong
%\usepackage{thmtools}
%\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
     Marginpar\marginpar{marginpar.}
     Footnote\footnote{footnote.}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "abuse" the [tablefootnote package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) with adding a `\spewnotes` command (a detailed explanation of `\spewnotes` is given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39500/6865).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spewnotes}{%
\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout%
\global\let\tfn@tablefootnoteprintout\relax%
\gdef\tfn@fnt{0}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
     Marginpar\marginnote{marginpar.}
     Footnote\tablefootnote{footnote.}
     Footnote\tablefootnote{another footnote.}
\end{theorem}
\spewnotes

Footnotes below.

\end{document}
```

The explanation *why* footnotes in a theorem do not work was already given by egreg in his answer, thus I do not repeat it here.

Answer (score 4):

`thmbox` includes the statement of theorems inside boxes and footnotes can't appear there; try

```
\mbox{a footnote\footnote{Missing}}
```

The same happens for `\marginpar`, because it uses the same mechanism of `\footnote`.

You can use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, as explained in the LaTeX guides. For `\marginpar` there is `\marginnote` of the `marginnote` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
     Marginpar\marginnote{marginpar.}
     Footnote\footnotemark
\end{theorem}
\footnotetext{footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice.  What if I would like to `hyperref` two footnotes in the same theorem?

Comment: @ASdeL: To use hyperef just see my answer. The explanation of egreg is still correct, and he informed about the marginnote package, therefore +1 to his answer also from me.